# Subclipse and general SVN browser usage

Tags: svn

I am working on improving my workflow on Linux and today I'm looking at version control, on Windows I have tortoiseSVN which provides enough functionality for me, but on Linux I have been getting by so far by using the command line commands. Which is fine, but obviously having a GUI to display things will help productivity. I found myself starting to rely on the web interface provided by my repository host for viewing history details. I got Subclipse working, since I enjoy Eclipse CDT quite a bit, so I think this is a tool I will be using from now on.

Now what does not help productivity is the 1-2 second wait whenever I click on anything in Subclipse. Clearly it is accessing the remote repository each time.

Is there a way to set the system up so that it can instantly load up the stats related to each file? I would really love to be able to scan through a folder quickly, it helps me keep the "big picture" fresh on my mind, but I'm certainly not going to do this if it takes as long as it does now.

Surely if I created a clone of the repository on my local machine I can get near instant data access times. The bonus of this is I'll notice a pleasant speed up when browsing TortoiseSVN logs on Windows as well, provided I make my repo accessible to both OS's, on an NTFS partition for instance.

So I would need to then be able to clone the repository to my local disk whenever any changes are committed. How might I automate this?

I'm guessing that a SVN checkout copy does not contain all of the repository data which these browsers are accessing, so it won't do me any good to hunt for an option to link up with a checked out local copy: It won't have the data to display an annotated file for instance, the local checked out copy has just the file itself (at whatever revision I specified during checkout) and whatever metadata is in the .svn dirs.

Please correct me if I got any of this wrong. I have put together all of these conclusions from experience using the software rather than reading actual documentation (which I'd like to have done but really can't spend the time to).

Update: After a little bit of digging it looks like there is a command more or less designed to do exactly what I need, `svnsync`. I really don't want to screw anything up here though because I do not have my repository backed up and I did not manually set it up, I'm using [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/)'s free service, which has been stellar, by the way.

Once a mirror is set up, though, and once I get it to automatically sync when updates are committed, it will function both as a cache and as a backup. It would be very handy. I wonder if I can directly checkout from a read-only mirror of a repository. It would make sense. I just wouldn't be able to commit changes to it.

So my real actual question is, how might I go about setting up this kind of a sync/mirror of the repo? I'm not looking to host the local repo to the network or anything, all I want is to be able to tell my SVN client (Subclipse or TortoiseSVN) to use this local repo to pull data from. One potential pitfall is that I'm not sure what kind of access I have to my base repository to set up the sync. Conceptually it should be a read-only operation but it's gotta be able to somehow "push" updates when I commit changes.

Update 2: Alright, I found a [helpful blog post](http://www.workhabit.com/labs/moving-svn-repository-hosted-service), this code gave me a duplicate repo:

```
svnadmin create /tmp/localsvn
echo '#!/bin/sh' > /tmp/localsvn/hooks/pre-revprop-change
chmod +x /tmp/localsvn/hooks/pre-revprop-change
svnsync init file:///tmp/localsvn https://your.unfuddle.com/svn/your_root
svnsync sync file:///tmp/localsvn
```

I didn't put mine in `/tmp/` but it's very straightforward.

My access to this repo works brilliantly with Subclipse. It's quite fast.

Now the issue is how to go about getting the local repo automatically synchronized on commit.

Update 3: Alright so it looks like I basically need to set up the `post-commit` and `post-revprop-change` hooks on the server to call svnsync to access the mirror. It couldn't really be done in any other way either and it makes sense...

I think I'll just end up making a script and call it whenever I want to update my local repo.

Comment: You have to have **pre-revprop-change** in mirror in order to have pure read-only (for *users*) repository. And instead of post-commit hook on *mirrored* repository you can use cron-job on *mirror* repository - the cost is just small delay in sync

Comment: Oooh that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is `git`. I've been very happy with it.